# get ansible groups by looping with_items

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to get the inventory host group names  by below process which is not working

```
- debug:
   msg: "{{ groups['{{ item }}'] }}"
  with_items: "{{ vm.stdout_lines }}"
```

**this is what actually I'm trying to do**
I will get a list of servers by a shell script

```
    - name: Getting the servers list
      shell: |
        sh getServers.sh
      register: vm
```

Then adding them into inventory by add_host

```
    - name: Creating Logical host_group for each server
      add_host:
       name: "{{ item }}"
       groups: ["{{item }}"]
      with_items: "{{ vm.stdout_lines }}"
      register: inv
```

**Here I'm trying to get the only groups I've added in above step** instead of all groups

```
- debug:
   msg: "{{ groups['{{ item }}'] }}"
  with_items: "{{ vm.stdout_lines }}"
```

Error is

```
{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute '{{ item }}'
```

Appreciate help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the syntax

```yaml
  msg: "{{ groups[item] }}"
```

Comment: it was able to give the first item but for the next item giving below error
`
ok: [localhost] => (item=localhost-1.local) => {
    "msg": [
        "localhost-1.local"
    ]
}

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute u'localhost-2.local'
`

Comment: got it by
`msg: '"{{ groups[item] }}"'` but getting output like this `"msg": "\"[u'localhost-1.local']\""`